# Set default values in two selects?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select, angularjs-scope

I have some problem with my selects. Here is code:

```
 <select ng-model="car" ng-options="car.name for car in cars track by car.id" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose model name</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <select ng-options="model.name for model in car.models track by model.id" ng-model="model" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose car</option>
  </select>
```

I want that when i visit this page that the two selects have default values. For example in first select -  "BMW" and in second - "528I" at the same time. I'm trying to do this solution:

```
<select ng-model="car" ng-init="car.id = 1" ng-options="car.name for car in cars track by car.id" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose model name</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <select ng-init="model.id = 5" ng-options="model.name for model in car.models track by model.id" ng-model="model" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose car</option>
  </select>
```

But it work only for the fisrt select. (And when i choose the name in first select with name with id = 1, the second select to switch to the model with id = 5;)

I don't know how to reailze default values in two selects at the same time.
Have you any ideas?

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sVMWtD7lowJJC1kcLIjZ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `ng-init`, like this:

```
  <select ng-init="car=cars[0]" ng-model="car" ng-options="car.name for car in cars" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose model name</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <select ng-init="model=car.models[0]" ng-options="model.name for model in car.modelsd" ng-model="model" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose car</option>
  </select>
```

### UPDATE

The syntax of your `select` was a bit off, you actually don't need to use `track by` unless you are grouping the values of your select, which you are not. I think that what you actually wanted was to have the model bound to the `id` of the 'car' rather than having the model bound to the car itself. If that's what you want you could do it like this:

```
  <select ng-init="car=1" ng-model="car" ng-options="car.id as car.name for car in cars" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose model name</option>
  </select>
```

But then you would have to do something very awkward in order to render the second select with the models of the car, because in that case your variable `car` would be an `int` (the id of the car), not the 'car' object, so you would have to do something like this:

```
  <select ng-init="model=5" ng-model="model" ng-options="model.id as model.name for model in ((cars | filter:{id:car})[0].models)" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose car</option>
  </select>
```

Which is just as awkward as it looks, but if that's what you want... well, here you have an example:

### [Working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/0XejrJUgn5wRXJ2VFxwS?p=preview)

A better idea in my opinion would be to have the models pointing to the objects, and if you want to initialize the selects through the `id`, you could do this in the `ng-init` :

```
  <select ng-init="car=(cars|filter:{id:1})[0]" ng-model="car" ng-options="car.name for car in cars" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose model name</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <select ng-init="model=(car.models|filter:{id:5})[0]" ng-options="model.name for model in car.models" ng-model="model" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose car</option>
  </select>
```

### [Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wp2oqKCidmbl2tZJvDT8?p=preview)

Comment: Ou! I have some else question . Can I use 'id' in place of array indexes?

Comment: @RomanA. Sure thing! Give me a minute, I will update the answer

Comment: It's really help! You awesome! @Josep

Answer (score 1):

You may use ng-model attribute in your controller and assign a default variable like

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" >
    <form>
        <select ng-model="myForm.car">
            <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
            <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
            <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <div>
        {{myForm.car}}
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
            .controller("MyController", function($scope) {
                $scope.myForm = {};
                $scope.myForm.car  = "nissan";
            } );
</script>
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/suholifadixa/1/edit)

and go through this link so that you will come to know form handling in angularjs:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/forms.html

Comment: Its same as accepted answer. That guy used ng-init and I've used ng-model in controller thats it. :)

Comment: I looked for solution without any controllers and in my code i used ng-model too.